# Why the PATH variable is not working properly in wsl?

Tags: windows, bash, gcc, environment-variables, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm having problems to configure my PATH variable in wsl.

I installed the MinGW and I wanted to use the command gcc in the wsl terminal. So I put the path for gcc.exe through the .bashrc. The path for gcc.exe appears in the PATH variable, but yet the command doesn't work. Using the powershell instead, the command works normally, because I put the path to gcc.exe in windows.

I have tried absolutely all the solutions I found online but none of them worked.

[image]

```
felipe@Diana:/mnt/c/MinGW/bin$ gcc --version
Command 'gcc' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install gcc
felipe@Diana:/mnt/c/MinGW/bin$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/wsl/lib:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Oracle/Java/javapath:/mnt/c/Windows/system32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/:/mnt/d/Arquivos de Programas/Git/cmd:/mnt/c/Program Files/dotnet/:/mnt/c/Program Files/PostgreSQL/15/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/dotnet/:/mnt/c/Program Files/nodejs/:/mnt/c/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin:/mnt/c/Users/Felipe/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/mnt/c/Users/Felipe/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin:/mnt/c/Users/Felipe/AppData/Roaming/npm:/mnt/c/MinGW/bin:/snap/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/nodejs/:/mnt/c/MinGW/bin/
felipe@Diana:/mnt/c/MinGW/bin$ ls
addr2line.exe  gcc-ar.exe      ld.exe              libmpc-3.dll           mingw32-gcc-nm.exe      readelf.exe
ar.exe         gcc-nm.exe      libatomic-1.dll     libmpfr-4.dll          mingw32-gcc-ranlib.exe  size.exe
as.exe         gcc-ranlib.exe  libcharset-1.dll    libquadmath-0.dll      mingw32-gcc.exe         strings.exe
c++.exe        gcc.exe         libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll  libssp-0.dll           mingw32-make.exe        strip.exe
c++filt.exe    gcov-tool.exe   libgmp-10.dll       libstdc++-6.dll        mingwm10.dll            windmc.exe
cpp.exe        gcov.exe        libgomp-1.dll       mingw-get.exe          nm.exe                  windres.exe
dlltool.exe    gdb.exe         libiconv-2.dll      mingw32-c++.exe        objcopy.exe             zlib1.dll
dllwrap.exe    gdbserver.exe   libintl-8.dll       mingw32-g++.exe        objdump.exe
elfedit.exe    gprof.exe       libisl-15.dll       mingw32-gcc-6.3.0.exe  pthreadGC-3.dll
g++.exe        ld.bfd.exe      libmingwex-0.dll    mingw32-gcc-ar.exe     ranlib.exe
felipe@Diana:/mnt/c/MinGW/bin$ tail -n 3 ~/.bashrc
export PATH="$PATH:/mnt/c/Program Files/nodejs/"
export PATH="$PATH:/mnt/c/MinGW/bin/"
```

It is not the first time I have this problem. When I installed node through the browser, I tried to put it in PATH too, but it didn't work. I had to uninstall it and reinstall through the terminal for it to work.

Comment: Do you need to invoke it with `gcc.exe`? Genuine question, I don't know the answer.

Comment: You seem to be trying to run a Windows GCC from within WSL.  Maybe that's supposed to work, but I wouldn't have expected so.  I would have thought that you need to install a Linux GCC toolchain inside the WSL container, and use that.  Windows uses different formats for binary executables than Linux does.

Comment: But if you *could* run Windows binaries inside WSL, then you would definitely need to invoke them via their full names (*e.g.* `gcc.exe`).

Answer (score 1):

I found out the problem. The PATH variable was correct and the command line was indeed able to execute the gcc, however, it only worked when I typed gcc.exe. It seems like wsl has problems identifying commands properly, only working when you type it with the ".exe".

To solve this, I added "alias gcc = "gcc.exe"" in the .bashrc file. Now, to all the new commands I want to add to the PATH variable, I also need to add the alias so it works properly.